# Assigning values when two dfs have different indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dfs that look like this:

```
Symbol Sector      Sub-industry    Company     Weight      SectorSymbol
Ticker           
MMM    Industrials  Conglomerates   MCompany    0.602676   XLI
ABT    Health Care  Equipment       Abbott Lab  0.401900   XLV
ABBV   Health Care  Pharmaceuticals AbbVie Inc  0.550174   XLV
ACN    Info Tech    Consulting      Accenture   0.370650   XLK
ATVI   Info Tech    Entertainment   Activision  0.192788   XLK
```

and

```
                MMM     ABT     ABBV    ACN    ATVI
Date
2017-01-03      1.4     2.3     4.5     2.1    .7
2017-01-04      .8      3.1     5.2     1.8    1.2
2017-01-05      2.4     2.1     5.5     1.6    1.4
```

I am trying to apply the "Sector Symbol" value I defined in the first df to the tickers in the second df (MMM, ABT, ABBV, etc.) , so that my second df will recognize the symbol MMM as part of XLI, ABT as XLV, and so on.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Sector': ['Industrials'] + ['Health Care']*2 + ['Info Tech']*2,
     'Sub-industry': ['Conglomerates', 'Equipment', 'Pharmaceuticals', 'Consulting', 'Entertainment'],
     'Company': ['MCompany', 'Abbott Lab', 'AbbVie Inc', 'Accenture', 'Activision'],
     'Weight': [.602676, .4019, .550174, .37065, .192788],
     'SectorSymbol': ['XLI', 'XLV', 'XLV', 'XLK', 'XLK']},
    index=pd.Index(['MMM', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ACN', 'ATVI'], name='Symbol Ticker')
    )[['Sector', 'Sub-industry', 'Company', 'Weight', 'SectorSymbol']]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'MMM': [1.4, .8, 2.4], 
                    'ABT': [2.3, 3.1, 2.1], 
                    'ABBV': [4.5, 5.2, 5.5], 
                    'ACN': [2.1, 1.8, 1.6], 
                    'ATVI': [.7, 1.2, 1.4]},
                  index=pd.Index(['2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05'], name='Date')
                  )[['MMM', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ACN', 'ATVI']]
```

The expected output would include the numerical values assigned to a ticker, where the program would recognize that ticker as part of "XLI, XLV, XLK", so like that I could search the values of MMM in df2, and the program would show me the excess movement #'s and what family its in (XLI)

Comment: sorry - see edit

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The #'s in the second df are called "excess movement", i want to find the average excess movement of all the stocks in XLI, XLV, XLK

Comment: so need to assign a Sector Symbol to the columns in df2

Comment: Thats half of it, but I still need the tickers to be assigned to a "Sector Symbol" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a dictionary mapping symbols to sector symbols.

2) Use a list comprehension to get an ordered mapping of all sector symbols for the relevant symbols.  Use `get` on the dictionary to allow for unmapped securities (see comments below).

3) Use `groupby` on the sector symbols and take the mean.

```
d = df1['SectorSymbol'].to_dict()
sector_symbols = [d.get(symbol) for symbol in df2]
>>> df2.groupby(sector_symbols, axis=1).mean()
            XLI  XLK   XLV
Date                      
2017-01-03  1.4  1.4  3.40
2017-01-04  0.8  1.5  4.15
2017-01-05  2.4  1.5  3.80
```

Comment: thanks - but in the future, if I don't want the full XLK , and say just want 3 of those stocks in that sector , how do I go about that?

Comment: `df2.groupby(sector_symbols, axis=1).mean()` would do instead of double transposing?

Comment: @thomas.mac You would need to to modify your dictionary `d` so that only the three names you care about map to XLK and the remaining names you don't care about map to NaN.

Comment: awesome that works - just one last error I get is that I have this previous value I defined (the benchmark) and it doesn't belong to a Sector Symbol, it says Key error : '^EOX' , how do I bypass that?

Comment: Did you want to map it to anything or just ignore it?

Comment: just wanted to ignore it

Answer (score 1):

IIUIC, Using `rename` and dict from two columns of `df1`

```
In [639]: df2.rename(columns=df1['SectorSymbol'].to_dict())
Out[639]:
            XLI  XLV  XLV  XLK  XLK
Date
2017-01-03  1.4  2.3  4.5  2.1  0.7
2017-01-04  0.8  3.1  5.2  1.8  1.2
2017-01-05  2.4  2.1  5.5  1.6  1.4
```

And, to merge column by mean

```
In [641]: dff = df2.rename(columns=df1['SectorSymbol'].to_dict())

In [642]: dff.groupby(dff.columns, axis=1).mean()
Out[642]:
            XLI  XLK   XLV
Date
2017-01-03  1.4  1.4  3.40
2017-01-04  0.8  1.5  4.15
2017-01-05  2.4  1.5  3.80
```